# Is using id field in @AllArgsConstructor while using Spring JPA correct?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, lombok

Using `spring-boot` and JPA I have an `Entity` I want to use lombok to reduce boilerplate code. However in my entity there is the `id` field. Shall I put it in the constructor arguments with `@AllArgsConstructor` or shall I eliminate it from theargument list (somehow, how?) due to being auto-generated with the `@id` and `@GeneratedValue` annotations?

code:

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor // JPA requires empty constructor
@AllArgsConstructor // ? is id in constuctor needed?

@Getter
@Setter
@ToString(exclude = {"room", "customer"})
public class Reservation {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    private Room room;
    private Customer customer;
    private Date dateFrom;
    private Date dateTo;    
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For your question in code:

> @AllArgsConstructor // ? is id in constuctor needed?

No it is not needed. Furthermore, for your question in the title:

> Is using id field in @AllArgsConstructor while using Spring JPA correct?

Field `id` it is not recommended to be exposed to any constructor or setter unless there is a very good reason for that. Field `id` should be manipulated only by JPA implementation.

Note that this expose happens also when you declare `@Setter` on `Reservation` class level.

This can be avoided to remove annotation from class level and annotate each field to expose but easier way is to use inheritance.

You can create a base class like:

```
@Entity
@Getter
// Choose your inheritance strategy:
//@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
//@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class BaseEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
}
```

Note that it does not have setter for field `id`. Extend above class like:

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString(exclude = {"room", "customer"})
public class Reservation extends BaseEntity {
    private Room room;
    private Customer customer;
    private Date dateFrom;
    private Date dateTo;    
}
```

and the constructors & setters will be the following:

```
Reservation r1 = new Reservation();
Reservation r2 = new Reservation(room, customer, dateFrom, dateTo);

r1.setRoom(room);
r1.setCustomer(customer);
r1.setDateFrom(dateFrom);
r1.setDateTo(dateTo);
```

and there is no way - other that reflection that JPA uses - to set the field `id`.

I do not know how [spring-data-jpa](/questions/tagged/spring-data-jpa) exactly does setting the `id` but as there is a keyword JPA and tag [jpa](/questions/tagged/jpa) I assumes this is a JPA thing and that setter for field `id` is not actually needed at all.

Comment: @pirhhp Can I use ONLY `@MappedSuperclass` for the `BaseEntity` instead of `@Entity @Getter` and `@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)`? While leaving the `Reservation` as it is in you code?

Comment: Yes. Actually while `BaseEntity` is abstract you can leave even the `@MappedSuperclass` out if not needed for other reasons. But do you really want to get rid of getter for id?

Comment: but without `@MappedSuperclass` will it include the `id` in the subclasses entities in db while only leaving the `@Getter` or the `@MappedSuperclass @Getter` is required?

Comment: I am using OpenJPA and it works with or without quite well. Leaving `@MappedSuperclass` out however disables for examples using `@AttributeOverride` in inheriting classes. But `id` will be generated as it should.

Answer (score 2):

A comment for the Lombok part: There is no way to exclude field from the `@AllArgsConstructor` (without using inheritance). For a limited constructor, you can only use `@RequiredArgsConstructor`, but this will generally not help you for JPA entities.

Comment: Yes. About this detail is an another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48790494/6413377)

Answer (score 1):

In this case `spring-data` uses setters to set values, so `@AllArgsConstructor` is not needed.

Comment: In this case `@AllArgsConstructor` is actually harmful. The `@Id` should not be written to in client code. See the answer from @pirho for an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is when id is auto generated by jpa and your are using lombok to avoid boilerplate code.

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Patient {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long reg;

    @NotNull
    private String name;
    @NotNull
    private String gender;
    @NotNull
    private String specimen;
    @NotNull
    private String contact;
    @NotNull
    private String cnic;
    @NotNull
    private String referred_by;

    public Patient(String name, String gender, String specimen, String contact, String cnic, String referred_by) {
        this.name = name;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.specimen = specimen;
        this.contact = contact;
        this.cnic = cnic;
        this.referred_by = referred_by;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || Hibernate.getClass(this) != Hibernate.getClass(o)) return false;
        Patient patient = (Patient) o;
        return reg != null && Objects.equals(reg, patient.reg);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return getClass().hashCode();
    }
}
```

simply used a custom constructor excluding id field and it works.