# Use Lombok @RequiredArgsConstructor without @NonNull

Tags: java, lombok

I have something like this:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private LocalDate date = null;
}
```

I need a constructor for the name attribute only, but it is not working. If I use `@NonNull` it will build the constructor I need, but for my case the name should be able to be null, can not be final either. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: If the `name` can be `null`, then what is the difference to the name not being required?

Comment: basically the `date` field is new, so without the `name` constructor I would have to do a huge refactor throughout the whole application to change every call to the constructor

Comment: Do you need other cosntructors? Or do you explicitly want **only** the name constructor?

Comment: Yes, I also need the AllArgsConstructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lombok `@RequiredArgsConstructor` has no such option currently.

You have at least two options:

1. Just code the constructor `public Person(String name)` without help of [lombok](/questions/tagged/lombok) annotations.
2. Use inheritance - which might be a bit overkill solution in your case but might be handy in some cases - as presented below:

   - Create a base class that holds all the fields you do not want to be in `Person` constructor:

     ```
     public abstract class BasePerson {
         private LocalDate date = null;
     }
     ```
   - Let your `Person` class extend above with the fields you need in constructor but want to be `null` also, with `@AllArgsConstructor`:

     ```
     @AllArgsConstructor
     public abstract class Person extends BasePerson {
         private String name;
     }
     ```